# Best way to show image based of dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am loading image from a url usig sdwebimage and putting it in a uiimageviww, it working perfectly,but since of all the image size differences the image sometime is a little pit distorted or the ratio from width to height is making it small,note( iam using aspects fit),my question is how to know the best width/height sizes so i can redefine the width and height uiimageview

Comment: In the completion block, get the size of the `UIImage` and resize your `UIImageView` if needed to that ratio?

Comment: Thank you,but sometimes is image is being loadedwith an original size bigger than the screen width and height,or if the height is much larger than width,how to know which size will represent the image. Better

Comment: Use aspects fill then? I don't understand your issue. Is it about coding? Because you have to decide what to do to manage different size. I'm wondering if it's only about "Logic" and UI experience rather than coding.

Comment: Have you considered using a vector image? If you're working with iOS 11 you can use Single Scale in the Attributes Inspector, change the Width Class value to Any and check the Preserve Vector Data checkbox.

I haven't tried it loading the image from a URL, but it might be worth exploring.

Comment: Users are upload the image,my issue is that even when using aspects fits the image automatically resized according to the layout to the uiimage,right.what i mean is that how to get uimageview width and height to achieve best look with ascpects fits